# Bloquear file get content

Tags: php, htaccess

Tem alguma forma de bloquear os site de usar file get content e cópiar a página do meu site? estão criando "bots" do meu site, creio que seja com isso, será que tem alguma forma de bloquear com htaccess ou php?

Comment: Utilizar o *JavaScript* para renderizar teu site, dessa forma, o PHP não conseguirá capturar o código fonte "completo".

Comment: Só teria como dessa forma? Conhece o cloudflare? Sabe se nele tem como?

Comment: A forma indicada não é a única. O [*CloudFlare*](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171416-How-do-I-block-bots-and-crawlers-) pode ajudá-lo.